# What are some statistical models used in business?

Tags: methodology

I am looking for some interesting statistical models and 'rules' that are very useful in a business perspective. Strictly speaking, depending on the business case each statistical method or model can have application on business, but I am interested only on those who are strictly created on business prespective. Some examples are:

- Shopping Basket analysis
- Knapsack Problem
- Benford's Law
- Forecasting Models

Comment: This question is too broad because as you already noticed "depending on the business case each statistical method or model can have application on business". As a comment: Knapsack Problem is a theoretical optimization problem; Forecasting Models were not designed and are not used only in business; on another hand $t$-test was designed for business problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-test#History) -- does it make it a "business" tool?

Answer (score 2):

Marketing science is jampacked with examples of applied business models:

- Customer lifetime value models are a forward-looking estimate over some time horizon of customers' value to a business
- Marketing mix models are used to evaluate the effectiveness of marketing spend (advtg, promotions, pricing, etc.) as well as for media vehicle allocation
- RFM (reach-frequency-monetary value) models are used in direct marketing as a customer targeting tool
- Recommender system models are used to suggest possible next product purchases, given a series of observed purchases, as used most prominently and effectively by Amazon
- Machine learning models are seeing wide and expanding use in business for a multitude of uses including information retrieval, driverless cars, communication targeting, deep learning, etc.
- Regression models can be used to rank the relative importance of quantitative factors impacting a process, any process. This information can be used to target those variables that are key, focusing decision-making

This is a completely partial and inadequate list but you get the idea...